# Separating concerns in a DSL using MTL

Tags: haskell, testing, dsl, monad-transformers

I'm writing a small DSL using monad-transformers following the ideas presented
here [here](https://gist.github.com/ocharles/6b1b9440b3513a5e225e). For the sake of
illustration I present a small subset here.

```
class Monad m => ProjectServiceM m where
  -- | Create a new project.
  createProject :: Text -- ^ Name of the project
                -> m Project
  -- | Fetch all the projects.
  getProjects :: m [Project]
  -- | Delete project.
  deleteProject :: Project -> m ()
```

The idea of this DSL is to be able to write API-level tests. To this end, all
these actions `createProject`, `getProjects`, `deleteProject` will be
implemented by REST calls to a web-service.

I also wrote an DSL to write expectations. An snippet is given below:

```
class (MonadError e m, Monad m) => ExpectationM e m | m -> e where
  shouldContain :: (Show a, Eq a) => [a] -> a -> m ()
```

And you could imagine that more DSL's can be added to the mix for logging, and
performance metrics [see the gist linked above](https://gist.github.com/ocharles/6b1b9440b3513a5e225e).

With these DSL is possible to write some simple tests like the following:

```
createProjectCreates :: (ProjectServiceM m, ExpectationM e m) => m ()
createProjectCreates = do
  p <- createProject "foobar"
  ps <- getProjects
  ps `shouldContain` p
```

Two interpreters are shown below:

```
newtype ProjectServiceREST m a =
  ProjectServiceREST {runProjectServiceREST :: m a}
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)

type Error = Text
instance (MonadIO m, MonadError Text m) => ProjectServiceM (ProjectServiceREST m) where
  createProject projectName = return $ Project projectName
  getProjects = return []
  deleteProject p = ProjectServiceREST (throwError "Cannot delete")

newtype ExpectationHspec m a =
  ExpectationHspec {runExpectationHspec :: m a}
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)

instance (MonadError Text m, MonadIO m) => ExpectationM Text (ExpectationHspec m) where
  shouldContain xs x = if any (==x) xs
                       then ExpectationHspec $ return ()
                       else ExpectationHspec $ throwError msg
    where msg = T.pack (show xs) <> " does not contain " <> T.pack (show x)
```

Now to run the scenario `createProjectCreates` the monad transformers can be
stacked in different ways. One way I found it makes sense is:

```
runCreateProjectCreates :: IO (Either Text ())
runCreateProjectCreates = ( runExceptT
                            . runExpectationHspec
                            . runProjectServiceREST
                            ) createProjectCreates
```

Which requires:

```
instance ProjectServiceM (ProjectServiceREST (ExpectationM (ExceptT Text IO)))
instance ExpectationM Text (ProjectServiceREST (ExpectationM (ExceptT Text IO)))
```

The problem with this is that either the instances of `ProjectSeviceM` have to
know about `ExpectationM` and create instances for it, or vice-versa. These
instances can be readily created by using the `StandaloneDeriving` extension, e.g.:

```
deriving instance (ExpectationM Text m) => ExpectationM Text (ProjectServiceREST m)
```

However it'd be nice if this could be avoided, since I'm leaking some
information to either implementations of the DSL's. Can the problem above be
overcome?

Answer (score 0):

The concrete constructors for your monad stack don't have to correspond directly to the `mtl`-style type classes. [This article and Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/36e45c/mtl_is_not_a_monad_transformer_library/) are relevant. The `mtl` class `MonadState s m` has a generic dumb implementation in `StateT`, but you can instantiate `MonadState` for `ReaderT (IORef s) IO` too, or for a CPS variant. Ultimately, you remain abstract in how you want the effect to be handled, you just require that it is handled.

Suppose instead you wrote two abstract monad transformers:

```
newtype ProdT m a = ProdT { runProdT :: ... }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadTrans, ...)
newtype TestT m a = TestT { runTestT :: ... }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadTrans, ...)
```

and you then define the instances you require. Instead of needing to write all the pass through instances, you can just write the ones you need directly.

As an aside, I would recommend *not* defining type classes if they are trivial combinations of other classes. The class/instance definitions for

```
class (MonadError e m, Monad m) => ExpectationM e m | m -> e where
    shouldContain :: (Show a, Eq a) => [a] -> a -> m ()
```

works just as well as

```
shouldContain :: (MonadError e m, Show a, Eq a) => [a] -> a -> m ()
```

You already *have* the ability to alter the base monad, as long as it has `MonadError`. A test implementation would possibly be

```
newtype ExpectationT m e a = ExpectationT { runExpectation :: WriterT [e] m a }

instance Monad m => MonadError (ExpectationT m e) e where
    throwError = ExpectationT . tell
    -- etc..
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `shouldContain`. I do understand that I can define my own mtl instances, however it is not clear how I could use `ProdT` and `TestT` for the problem at hand. To clarify, as soon as I start stacking monad-transformers it will be required that instances of one class implement another class in the stack.